# How to make a cron job run during business hours on Google App Engine cron.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I've read the docs, but I'm scratching my head on how to do this. I want to run a cron job during business hours. So my cron.yaml would look something like:

```
cron:
- description: My Cool Cron Job 
  url: /myCoolCronJob.php 
  schedule: every 5 minutes from 06:00 to 19:00 every monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
  timezone: America/Los_Angeles
```

That doesn't work, obviously. But it should give you an idea of what I want to do. How can I make this cron job run during business hours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Schedule format doesn't offer a combination between the high-frequency

```
every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
```

and the low frequency

```
("every"|ordinal) (days) ["of" (monthspec)] (time)
```

The way to obtain what you desire is to:

- configure the high frequency portion of the schedule in `cron.yaml`:

  `schedule: every 5 minutes from 06:00 to 19:00`
- check the weekday condition inside the cron job itself, at the beginning and exiting without doing anything if the day of execution is Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: I wish, GCP could make it easier to use. It is too limited to configure at the moment. Coding to support configuration/schedule is not a good idea but this seems to be only option left.