# Specifying a startdate for cronjobs in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, yaml

I've set up a cron.yaml file for my app to run some cronjobs, i.e. every 2 mins, every 15 mins... Is it possible to specify the tasks to start from a specific date? Say I want to start running all cronjobs from 6th december 2017?

Answer (score 1):

The GAE cron [Schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#schedule_format) doesn't have direct support for the functionality you seek.

However it's relatively easy to obtain such functionality, see [How to make a cron job run during business hours on Google App Engine cron.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248214/how-to-make-a-cron-job-run-during-business-hours-on-google-app-engine-cron-yaml/46254697#46254697)